# Can i use Try catch to check if file exists with image("C:\\filename")

Tags: c#, bitmap, try-catch

```
try 
{ 
 if (!File.Exists("File.Ext")) 
    throw new FileNotFoundException(); 

} 
catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
{ 
   // your message here. 
}
```

while writing this post i found the code above , thinking there must be a way doing it in one block
i am trying to check for erros reading bmp with

```
Bitmap b2;
b2 = new Bitmap("g:\\btmp1.bmp");
```

so if theres a problem assigning the file to "b2" it will give an error

```
string notExst = "";
Bitmap b2;
try
{
    b2 = new Bitmap("g:\\ba.bmp");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    throw e.Tostring(); \\ would it be ok to 
 \\ msgbox.show(e.Tostring()) insted of throw ?

}
```

i guess i made a syntax error in my Try Catch, what is the right way?
thanks.

After Edit
Joey, i dont understand your answer i want to be informed and break out of method accordingly 
instead of crush

finally

```
public bool TryGetBitMap(string FilePath)
{
    string NotExstMsg = "The file: " + FilePath + "Could Not Be Found!";
    bool exst = false;
    if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
         MessageBox.Show(NotExstMsg);
    else exst = true;
    return exst;
}

private void ButScreenCupt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string FilePath1 = "g:\\a.bmp";
    string FilePath2 = "g:\\b.bmp";
    Bitmap b1, b2;
    bool isSuccess1 = TryGetBitMap(FilePath1);
    bool isSuccess2 = TryGetBitMap(FilePath2);
    if (isSuccess1 && isSuccess2)
    {
        b1 = new Bitmap(FilePath1);
        pictureBox1.Image = b1;
        b2 = new Bitmap(FilePath2);
        pictureBox2.Image = b2;
        dd = ComparingImages.Compare(b1, b2);

        MessageBox.Show(dd.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of catching an exception you're just re-throwing?

Comment: If the exception isn't thrown then the file obviously exists. Otherwise there'd be a `FileNotFoundException`. Which is what you should catch instead of the most generic `Exception`. If you don't see the results it's probably because you catch the re-thrown exception somewhere else.

Comment: @Joey ok i will reEdit My Code cause i dont understand

Comment: Exception handling is relatively expensive.  If your application accepts a user supplied filename and opens the file for display, then the overhead may not be a problem.  If it is processing thousands of images and you have reason to expect a fair number are missing, then it may make more sense to make an explicit check for existence of the file.  The file could vanish between the test and the loading, but that's life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your own method using a TryGet pattern.

```
bool isSuccess = TryGetBitMap("g:\\ba.bmp",b2);
```

Comment: i am answering my question following your reference Justin, like i was writig in the initial question after noting the first block of code thought ther's a smaller code ..

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap b2;
try
{
    b2 = new Bitmap("g:\\ba.bmp");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException notExst)
{
   //enter your message here
}
```

No need to throw the exception inside catch.

Comment: you are declaring a string with the same name as the filenotfoundexception in the code you posted.

Comment: @Jaguar
 Not Working (?) can u check your code ? (gives me Parameter is not valid.) pointing to the try block

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare **notExst**  variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaguar mentioned, you can catch a FileNotFoundException if one is thrown by the Bitmap class.
Exception handling causes the call stack to unwind. If you can check for the existence of a file using an if-else statement, that would be preferable.